# How to model an Aperture from a camera (and possibly animate it)

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, camera

so i'm curious if i wanted to create an aperture model like in a camera. And then animate it to change apertures how would i do this. More specifically i want to know how to use the array modifier to make them act like a real aperture.
thank you